# facebook keep getting "This content is no longer available" error when trying to share content on another timeline

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

So ive set up a share button on my website using the FB JS SDK and have included a simple generic share button. Ive updated all OG tags and checked in facebook degugger and im not getting any errors.

The share button works fine when sharing to my own timeline, only seems to error when trying to share to someone elses

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '1636640659907661',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.4'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div
  class="fb-like"
  data-share="true"
  data-width="450"
  data-show-faces="true">
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean 'share to someone else's'? You mean when someone else uses the Like button it doesn't post to their profile? Is your app still in Development Mode? If so, things posted by the app are visible only to admins, developers, testers of the app

Comment: @Igy Is this needed for basic page shares? I thought the approval process was only needed for rich opengraph stories. I can also use the share button to post the link in a private message and on group feeds as well as on my own feed.. its just posting on another users feed that is bringing this up.

Comment: There's no approval needed to take your app out of development mode [ just a privacy policy URL and contact email address], but until you do, the app and any content it creates can only be seen by you (and any other admins, developers, testers, the app has) - see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/register#development-mode